# delete specific files and retain some

Tags: linux, bash

so I have this directory that includes these **.js** and **.yml** files and one folder named as **config**

```
pogi@gwapo-pah:~$ ls 

index.cat.js
index.bird.js
index.dog.js
index.monkey.js
function.yml
config
```

I would like to execute a one-liner bash command that would perform these

> find if "index.dog.js" exists, and if none then exit
>
> find if "index.dog.js" exists, and if present then remove only the
>   other *.js files and retain **index.dog.js**, **function.yml** and the folder **config**

if command is success then the files from folder shold look like this:

```
index.dog.js
function.yml
config
```

these is so far I tried however I'm not able to continue the missing logic

```
if [ -f index.dog.js ] ; then echo 'exists' ; fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test -f index.dog.js && find . -name \*.js -not -name index.dog.js -exec rm {} +
```

Explanation:

`test` is a way to do `if` without all the extra syntax, if you don't need the `else`.

`&&` is the "short circuit" (exit) you want if there is no dog file.

`find` looks for files using multiple criteria. In this case files whose name match *.js but are not the dog file.

`find` can then execute a command against the found files. The `{}` is a stand-in for the found files. The `+` means put all the filenames on one `rm` command, rather than running one command per file.

Answer (score 3):

```
shopt -s extglob
[[ -f index.dog.js ]] && rm !(index.dog).js
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `find` command:

```
[ -f "index.dog.js" ] && find . -maxdepth 1 -name \*.js -not -name index.dog.js -delete
```

`find` command search in current directory any file with `js` extension but `index.dog.js` and remove it.

replace `.` with folder name if you are not inside directory where are file.

Answer (score 1):

Test if "index.dog.js" exists, if it does, use `find` to yield all *.js files (but not index.dog.js), and delete them.

**EDIT** As John Kugelman correctly advises, best to avoid  `ls` due to possible inconsistencies with it.

```
[ -f "index.dog.js" ] && \
    find . -type f -not -name "index.dog.js" -name \*.js -exec rm {} +
```